# "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process" Error when trying to setup my Xamarin.Forms project with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem:**

I am getting the error below when I try to setup Firebase Cloud Messaging with my Xamarin.Forms app on Android.

`{Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xyz.AppXyz. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

**What I tried:**

This is my OnCreate method below, where I am testing to see if the token exists. I tried adding `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this)` to the beginning to see if that would work but it nothing has changed. I've looked at other threads similar to this but nothing has proven to be useful as of yet. I'm almost positive I followed the tutorial located [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) perfectly, but I guess I possibly missed a step. `google-services.json` IS added in the project, so it can't be that.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        try
        {
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string mess = ex.Message;
        }

        //FCM Notifications stuff
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                Log.Debug(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
            }
        }

        IsPlayServicesAvailable();
        try
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var mess = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction if anything is glaringly obvious, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. I solved my issue pretty quickly: I never set the BuildAction of my `google-services.json` to GoogleServicesJson. This instantly solved my problem and I was able to remove `FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);`.

Comment: Can you explain further?